# Pytorch - Loss for Object Localization

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I am trying to perform an object localization task with MNIST based on Andrew Ng's lecture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSwYGkTfOKk&list=PL_IHmaMAvkVxdDOBRg2CbcJBq9SY7ZUvs). I am taking the MNIST digits and randomly placing them into a 90x90 shaped image and predicting the digit and it's center point. When I train, I am getting very poor results and **my question is about whether or not my loss function is set up correctly.** I basically just take the CrossEntropy for the digit, the MSE for the coordinates, and then add them all up. Is this correct? I don't get any errors, but the performance is just horrendous.

My dataset is defined as follows (which returns the label and the x y coordinates of the center of the digit):

```
class CustomMnistDataset_OL(Dataset):

def __init__(self, df, test=False):
    '''
    df is a pandas dataframe with 28x28 columns for each pixel value in MNIST
    '''
    self.df = df
    self.test = test

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if self.test:
        image = np.reshape(np.array(self.df.iloc[idx,:]), (28,28)) / 255.
    else:
        image = np.reshape(np.array(self.df.iloc[idx,1:]), (28,28)) / 255.
    
    # create the new image
    new_img = np.zeros((90, 90)) # images will be 90x90
    # randomly select a bottom left corner to use for img
    x_min, y_min = randrange(90 - image.shape[0]), randrange(90 - image.shape[0])
    x_max, y_max = x_min + image.shape[0], y_min + image.shape[0]
    
    x_center = x_min + (x_max-x_min)/2
    y_center = y_min + (y_max-x_min)/2

    new_img[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max] = image
    
    label = [int(self.df.iloc[idx,0]), x_center, y_center] # the label consists of the digit and the center of the number
    sample = {"image": new_img, "label": label}
    
    return sample['image'], sample['label']
```

My training function is set up as follows:

```
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss_mse = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, loss_mse, optimizer):
    model.train() # very important... This turns the model back to training mode
    size = len(train_dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y0, y1, y2 = X.to(device), y[0].to(device), y[1].to(device), y[2].to(device)

        pred = model(X.float())
        # DEFINE LOSS HERE -------
        loss = loss_fn(pred[0], y0) + loss_mse(pred[1], y1.float()) + loss_mse(pred[2], y2.float())

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch*len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

Comment: i only see `x_center, y_center` ! what abt `height` & `width`

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar the digits are all 28x28 so I figured that would be a bit pointless. I am trying to slowly build up my experiment and was planning on changing the sizes of the digits later and incorporating them. Do you think that would be causing the loss to be unable to decrease?

Comment: I am seeing that the approach to just add loss functions together are ok from here (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-combine-multiple-criterions-to-a-loss-function/348/17)