# Object localization MNIST Tensorflow to Pytorch : Losses doesn't decrease

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, localization, bounding-box

I am trying to convert a Tensorflow object localization code into Pytorch. In the original code, the author use `model.compile` / `model.fit` to train the model so I don't understand how the losses of classification of the MNIST digits and box regressions work. Still, I'm trying to implement my own training loop in Pytorch.
The goal here is, after some preprocessing, past the MNIST digits randomly into a black square image and then, classify and localize (bounding boxes) the digit.

I set two losses : `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` and `nn.MSELoss` and I do `(loss_1+loss_2).backward()` to compute the gradients. I know it's the right way to compute gradients with two losses from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565817/pytorch-loss-for-object-localization) and [here](https://blog.paperspace.com/object-localization-pytorch-2/).

But still, my loss doesn't decrease whereas it collapses quasi-imediately with the Tensorflow code. I checked the model with `torchinfo.summary` and it seems behaving as well as the Tensorflow implementation.

EDIT :
I looked for the predicted labels of my model and it doesn't seem to change at all.
This line of code `label_preds, bbox_coords_preds = model(digits)` always returns the same values

`label_preds[0] = tensor([[0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)`

Here are my questions :

- Is my custom network set correctly ?
- Are my losses set correctly ?
- Why my label predictions don't change ?
- **Do my training loop work as well as the `.compile` and `.fit` Tensorflow methods ?**

Thanks a lot !

### PYTORCH CODE

```py
class ConvNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv2d_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2d_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2d_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.avgPooling2D = nn.AvgPool2d((2,2))
        self.dense_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=3136, out_features=128)
        
        self.dense_classifier = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        self.dense_regression = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=4)


    def forward(self, input):
        x = self.avgPooling2D(F.relu(self.conv2d_1(input)))
        x = self.avgPooling2D(F.relu(self.conv2d_2(x)))
        x = self.avgPooling2D(F.relu(self.conv2d_3(x)))
        x = nn.Flatten()(x)
        x = F.relu(self.dense_1(x))

        output_classifier = self.softmax(self.dense_classifier(x))
        output_regression = self.dense_regression(x)
        return [output_classifier, output_regression]

######################################################

learning_rate = 0.1
EPOCHS = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 64

model = ConvNetwork()
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
classification_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
regression_loss = nn.MSELoss()

######################################################

begin_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(EPOCHS) : 
    tot_loss = 0
    train_start = time.time()
    training_losses = []
    
    print("-"*20)
    print(" "*5 + f"EPOCH {epoch+1}/{EPOCHS}")
    print("-"*20)

    model.train()
    for batch, (digits, labels, bbox_coords) in enumerate(training_dataset):
        digits, labels, bbox_coords = digits.to(device), labels.to(device), bbox_coords.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        [label_preds, bbox_coords_preds] = model(digits)
        
        class_loss = classification_loss(label_preds, labels)
        box_loss = regression_loss(bbox_coords_preds, bbox_coords)

        training_loss = class_loss + box_loss
        training_loss.backward()
        
        optimizer.step()
        
        ######### print part #######################
        training_losses.append(training_loss.item())
        if batch+1 <= len_training_ds//BATCH_SIZE:
            current_training_sample = (batch+1)*BATCH_SIZE
        else:
            current_training_sample = (batch)*BATCH_SIZE + len_training_ds%BATCH_SIZE
        
        if (batch+1) == 1 or (batch+1)%100 == 0 or (batch+1) == len_training_ds//BATCH_SIZE +1:
            print(f"Elapsed time : {(time.time()-train_start)/60:.3f}",\
                  f" --- Digit : {current_training_sample}/{len_training_ds}",\
                  f" : loss = {training_loss:.5f}")
            if batch+1 == (len_training_ds//BATCH_SIZE)+1:
                print(f"Total elapsed time for training : {(time.time()-begin_time)/60:.3f}")
```

### ORIGINAL TENSORFLOW CODE

```py
def feature_extractor(inputs):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, activation='relu', kernel_size=3, input_shape=(75, 75, 1))(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    return x

def dense_layers(inputs):
  x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
  return x

def classifier(inputs):

  classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(inputs)
  return classification_output


def bounding_box_regression(inputs):
    bounding_box_regression_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = '4', name = 'bounding_box')(inputs)
    return bounding_box_regression_output


def final_model(inputs):
    feature_cnn = feature_extractor(inputs)
    dense_output = dense_layers(feature_cnn)

    classification_output = classifier(dense_output)
    bounding_box_output = bounding_box_regression(dense_output)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = [classification_output,bounding_box_output])
    return model
  
def define_and_compile_model(inputs):
  model = final_model(inputs)
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss = {'classification' : 'categorical_crossentropy',
                      'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                     },
              metrics = {'classification' : 'accuracy',
                         'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                        })
  return model

    

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(75, 75, 1,))
model = define_and_compile_model(inputs)


EPOCHS = 10 # 45
steps_per_epoch = 60000//BATCH_SIZE  # 60,000 items in this dataset
validation_steps = 1

history = model.fit(training_dataset,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                    validation_data=validation_dataset, 
                    validation_steps=validation_steps, epochs=EPOCHS)

loss, classification_loss, bounding_box_loss, classification_accuracy, bounding_box_mse = model.evaluate(validation_dataset, steps=1)
print("Validation accuracy: ", classification_accuracy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answering to myself about this bug :

What I found :
I figured that I use a `Softmax` layer in my code while I'm using the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` as a loss.

What this problem was causing :

- This loss already apply a `softmax` ([doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html))
- Apply a `softmax` twice must add some noise to the loss and preventing convergence

What I did : 
One should let a linear layer as an output for the classification layer.
An other way is to use the `NLLLoss` ([doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html?highlight=nllloss#torch.nn.NLLLoss)) instead and let the `softmax` layer in the model class.

Also : 
I don't fully understand how the `.compile()` and `.fit()` Tensorflow methods work but I think it should optimize the training one way or another (I think about the learning rate) since I had to decrease the learning rate to 0.001 in Pytorch to "unstick" the loss and makes it decrease.